# How can I escape an apostrophe inside a SQL query in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Here's my function:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX!A1:C"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Woman's blabla: blablabla'"),"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

I've tried adding another apostrophe:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX!A1:C"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Woman''s blabla: blablabla'"),"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

No luck.. and I've tried putting a backslash, no luck as well:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX!A1:C"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Woman/'s blabla: blablabla'"),"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

**EDIT:** The locale of the document is UK.

Comment: it looks like your using a forward slash in your example instead of a backslash

Comment: I've tried both.. no luck

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using double quotes around the word with the apostrophe

```
"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = ""Woman's blabla: blablabla"""
```

Comment: Edited my answer.. try again ? If if still doesn't work, can you share some sample data ?

Comment: This syntax is difficult to understand for me, but I just assumed that If I substituted the text for a variable (named/range) it was going to be fine, and it is. this is the same statement with the variable:
"SELECT * WHERE C="""&Enemy&""""

Answer (score 13):

If the string you're trying to match is in a cell, try surrounding the cell name with `""""` like so:

`=QUERY(Foo!A:B,"select A where B = " & """" & A1 & """" & "")`

Comment: There's a slightly simpler version of this too: `=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A WHERE B = """ & C1 & """")`. Note 4x quotes at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to generate an output like `SELECT * WHERE Col2 = "Woman's blabla: blablabla"` seems to be a valid solution. However, as mentioned, escaping characters with backslash `\` does not work for Google Sheets.

Searching for a workaround, I came across this [link](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/join-double-quotes-with-text-in-google-sheets/). It suggests using `char(34)` in place of double quotes, which is the working solution for me.

Accordingly, you can write

`=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX!A1:C"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = " & char(34) & "Woman's blabla: blablabla" & char(34)),"SELECT Col1, Col2")`

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting the double quotes in the source data through the function, you may need to swap out some of the quotes i added - I dont know what the text your searching for actually looks like  in your source data:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXX", SUBSTITUTE("XXXXXX!A1:C","""","'")),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'Woman's blabla: blablabla'"),"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

EDIT: