# Quotation marks and apostrophes in the same string in QUERY Google Sheets function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

I'm wondering how one might handle a query like this. Let's suppose I had the following text contained in Cell A2 of a spreadsheet:

```
Case Bakers' Flats 12" White Flour Tortillas 10/12ct
```

and needed to put the following formula into B2:

```
=QUERY(importrange("KEY", "DATA!A1:Z1000"), "select Col24 where (Col1 = '"&A2&"')")
```

It would produce an error.

My question is: Is there any way to avoid tripping up the query when the string I am using contains any assortment of quotation marks and apostrophes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets Query Language: escape apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991998/google-sheets-query-language-escape-apostrophe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Short answer

- To escape single quote / apostrophe, embrace the string containing an apostrophe between double quotes (`"`).
- To escape double quotes, apply a double substitution, first to remove the double-quotes, then to add them again.

## Explanation

Google Sheets QUERY built-in function automatically escape some characters by internally adding `\` before single quotes but it's doesn't work when the cell value to be used as the source for the criteria includes double quotes. As a workaround, the the use of double substitution is proposed.

### Example for single quote / apostrophe

Below table represents and spreadsheet range that contains

- Column A: The data source
- Cell B1:  The data value to be used in the criteria expression
- Cell C1: The following formula `=QUERY(A:A,"SELECT * WHERE A = """&B1&""" ")`

```
+---+---------+-----+-----+
|   |    A    |  B  |  C  |
+---+---------+-----+-----+
| 1 | I'm     | I'm | I'm |
| 2 | You're  |     |     |
| 3 | It's    |     |     |
| 4 | I am    |     |     |
| 5 | You are |     |     |
| 6 | It is   |     |     |
+---+---------+-----+-----+
```

### Example for single quote / apostrophe and double quotes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
   QUERY(
     SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"""","''"),
     "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = """&SUBSTITUTE(B1,"""","''")&""""
    ),
    "''",""""
 )
```

Note that instead of using a the letter A as identifier of the data source column it's used Col1.

## Reference

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score -1):

```
=query('Book list'!A:F,"select B,C,D,E where F=""free"" and D="""&E1&"""") - because:
```

Here are the formats for each type of literal:

String literals should be enclosed in either single or double quotes. Examples: `"fourteen"`, `'hello world'`, `"It's raining"`.

as mentioned in the reference above.