# How can I escape double and single quotes in google sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I have this query in google sheets cell:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:F, "SELECT * WHERE A='te'xt"text'", 0)
```

I can escape double quote like this: `text""text`

But how can I escape double and single quote? `te'xt"text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets Query Language: escape apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991998/google-sheets-query-language-escape-apostrophe)

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative would be to do some pre-processing (before the query)

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({regexmatch(Sheet1!A2:A, "te\'xt"&char(34)&"text"),Sheet1!A2:F}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6,Col7  where Col1 = true", 0))
```

The regex match will return 'true' for all rows matching the pattern. Then the query() selects only the rows with 'true' in Col1.