# How can I use query ends which have single quotes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I query `=Query(A:B;"Where B ends with 'HDD laptop 2.5''inch'";0)`, it will fail, because there's a `''` . Is there a way to still query with single quotes?
Sometimes I need to query column `BY`, but QUERY understands Column `BY` as `by`.

Comment: perhaps here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864405/how-can-i-escape-double-and-single-quotes-in-google-sheets-query?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  =Query(A:B,"Where B ends with ""HDD laptop 2.5''inch""",0)
```

and see if that works?

EDIT: if you want to query column BY you'll have to use back quotes around BY (because BY is a reserved word in the query language).

Example:

```
...where `BY` ends with ...
```