# Select query that contains a value from another cell that has a ' in the string

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I've got a select query in a Google Sheet, for the most part it works.
It's selecting a bunch of rows where a column equals a value in another cell.  For example:

```
WHERE G='" & K7 & "' AND Q is not Null order by Q Asc limit 3
```

I've just encountered a problem where if K7 which is a text value contains a ' in the cell the query doesn't work.  What do I need to include to ensure the query still works if it contains these values?

Comment: Use a parameterized query. This is what they exist to prevent. The malicious exploitation of this type of bug is known as SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how to do this?

Comment: K7 is imported from another source and is names.  The value of K7 will be different every time.

But other cells may have other values that also contain a ' so I need a method to deal with this.

Comment: That will depend entirely upon your RDBMS and your programmatic interface. If, on the other hand, you're using [the Google Sheets query function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42506783/696808) Is probably what you're actually looking for rather than a general SQL answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple displacement:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE({G:G, Q:Q}, "'", "♥"), 
 "where Col1 = '"&SUBSTITUTE(K7, "'", "♥")&"' 
    and Col2 is not null 
  order by Col2 asc 
  limit 3"), "♥", "'"))
```